# How to share the android screen without root?

Tags: android

I wonder screen-miracast between android and Window PC. 
I see 'mobizen' application.

That app is running on unroot device, and connect PC for Wifi, LTE.
'How to screen share like mobizen (Wifi, LTE) without root?'

If you dont know correctly, just hint pleaze. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A much better option in this case is AirDroid, with which you can even remotely access your device's camera, over your wifi (so it goes really far).
Check it out, much better than this pompous looking Mobizen :)